# Visual Studio 2012 not recognize unit tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I'm struggling with this issue several days. Visual Studio can't recognize tests in file so I cannot run or debug it. My colleges have own copy and works correctly.

I have tried:

1. Cleared \AppData\Roaming\JetBrains
2. Cleared cache inside Resharper, rebuild, deleted .suo file
3. Removed all addons: Code maid, Hide main menu, Productivity Power Tools    2012, VS Commands. VsVim and Ankh are installed.
4. Unchecked Resharper>Options>Unit Testing>Shadow-copy....,
   cleaned, rebuild.
5. Run VisualStudio as Administrator.
6. Test classes and methods are public.
7. Tried change TEST -> Test Settings ->
   Default Processor Architecture from x86 to x64.
8. Windows Update run and installed all updates VS Pro 2012 Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4
9. Installed lastest resharper version v7.....

Google is no longer for me, the results of which I had not seen, so guys do you have some tips?

Edit:

10. Tried http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23854211-MSTest-Unit-Testing-does-not-work-or-fails-with-error-with-ReSharper-7-1-x
11. Removed gallio and mbunit from references and download them via nuget.
12. Changed VisualStudio project type to be "testable" ->http://www.bryanavery.co.uk/post/2010/06/22/Running-Gallio-tests-within-Visual-Studio.aspx
13. When I create new class and try to code some tests, it doesn't work. The same as above. When I create new test solution then it works :(

Edit2:

Issue is not present if I use NUnit. So now it concerns to **MbUnit**.

Comment: I should add, when I create test solution then everything is OK. This case is for existing files. Tests are using MbUnit framework.

Comment: Your tests have the `[TestClass]` (or similar) attribute?

Comment: Yes indeed, `[TextFixture]` on the class and `[Test]` on the method.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't recognize"? Doesn't appear in Resharper's runner, doesn't appear in Visual Studio's runner? Were the tests recognized before in the same project/solution and suddenly they aren't? If a new solution has no problem, then the problem is in your current solution, not Visual Studio or Resharper

Comment: Doesn't recognize I mean, "Test explorer" and "Unit Test explorer" do not recognize tests in file. If on `[Test]` method I run "Debug Unit Test", resharper will show up message: "No tests found in file". Hmm project are download from repository, and on another computer works well.

Comment: Sorry to say, but I ran into this once as well. Creating a new test project would be fine, trying to get tests recognized in an existing project failed miserably. I ended up creating a new project and simply adding all the test class source files from the old project...

Answer (score 0):

My colleague found issue, I don't have installed **Gallio Resharper plugin**...

That's it. Thanks for every comment!